# strange bleedthrough in normal map baking (cycles, cage)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, normals

I am using a cycles cage bake for the normal map for a LP hammer. The normal map has some strange shapes for the "nobs" on the top of the hammer.[image]

As you can see the red nobs are mirrored on the other side. And if I turn of the mirror for the render, the nobs come out clean on one side but still weird and distorted on the other? Do the rays go through the object and take the back or what is it?

EDIT: Here is the link to blend-exchange: [image]